# Exception handling in fire and forget for C# 5 (in .net 4.5)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, error-handling, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

Consider the following "fire-and-forget" use case:

A caller requests some data from my method. My method checks the cache to see if the data is already there. If it's not, it fetches it from the source and caches it. The caller shouldn't need to wait for the caching to occur before getting his results and the method shouldn't prevent the caller from getting a result if the caching happens to fail. What I have today, looks like this:

```
public Foo GetFoo(string fooKey)
{
    // look for Foo with fooKey in cache
    // if Foo is not found, get Foo with fooKey from source
    // and assign it to local variable myFoo
    Task cacheTask 
           = Task.Run
                (
                    () => CacheFoo(myFoo)// fire-and-forget the caching of myFoo
                ); 
    return myFoo;
}
```

If CacheFoo throws an Exception it goes unobserved and eventually (in .Net 4.5) it gets swallowed up by the framework. I'd rather have a last shot at cleaning up the exception myself, but I don't want to block the current thread. What's the best way to do that?

Here is what I've tried

```
try
{
    ...
   cacheTask.ContinueWith
            (
                (e) => { 
                         if (cacheTask.IsFaulted) 
                            { 
                             /* log cacheTask.Exception */; 
                             } 
                        }
                , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted
            ); 
}
```

Is there a better way? Do I need the "if" statement on IsFaulted or is that redundant because I've already specified "OnlyOnFaulted"?

Any opinions/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would be nice if one can mark a task as fire-and-forget..so no Wait/ContinueWith possible. And since in this case no one is there to handle the exception it should crash the app so you have a nice dump file where you can watch at your local variables and the heap at the point in time the exception has been thrown...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Four things:

- No, you don't need the [Task.IsFaulted property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted%28v=vs.100%29.aspx); the callback will only fire if it's faulted
- You don't need to capture `cacheTask`; the `e` in your callback is the same task, so you might as well use that instead. (Then the same delegate can be used for *all* tasks.)
- If you're always logging in the same way, you may want to write an extension method on task to make it easy to do this
- As an alternative to adding a handler, you could consider subscribing to [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception.aspx) and performing logging there

Comment: I couldn't grasp. Is there any difference between .NET 4.0 and 4.5 in this? And what is it?

Comment: @ГеннадийВанинНовосибирск: Yes, there's a difference, although I'm not sure it's relevant here. .NET 4.0 would kill the whole process if a task faulted in an unobserved way. .NET 4.5 doesn't.

Comment: @ГеннадийВанинНовосибирск: a bit off topic, but it should also be noted that you can make 4.5 behave like 4.0 by setting the ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions setting in the config to "true". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/jj160346.aspx